# Trouble in Natural Earth Shapefile "jumps" read using GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, polygon, geotools, natural-earth

I'm using GeoTools 12.0 to read in Natural Earth data.

I'm really happy with the performance, and ease of implementation.

But, I'm having trouble reading in very large polygon data.  The 110M Ocean dataset contains two polygons: one for the Caspian Sea, and the other for the rest of the World (ROW).

But, in the ROW polygon I'm getting lots of "jumps" in the data.  For example, record 3665 is for this location in North America: `(-93.61275590694041, 74.97999726022442, NaN)`.

The next record, 3666 is for this location in the UK: `(-3.0050048486351955, 58.635000108466244, NaN)`

Does anybody know if the data includes some other specifier that indicates that the polygon *breaks* between these two points?

Comment: Can you post a picture? There is no expectation that following rows are near each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the bottom of my troubles: I wasn't aware of how it's possible to represent a series of polygons and their holes using sub-regions:
http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Types/PolyFillType.htm